# What is the best way to load records in DynamoDB using Pyspark(glue)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I have an use case to load multiple records into DynamoDB. I am thinking of using Glue with sparck context. What is the function I need to look into? PutItem runs for long, is there an alternative that I can use?

Tried using PutItem, but got no where. I am loading 30,000+ records in one go and PutItem is dead slow.

Answer (score 0):

Glue has a DynamoDB connector which is the easiest way to write from Glue:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb